# Script no longer works (it has worked for years now)

Tags: google-sheets, scripting, move

We have a script that will move a row of data to another sheet when it's marked "completed". It stopped working on April 22 after working for more than 5 years.

When I debug it, I get this error message

```
Error   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onEdit  @ Code.gs:3
```

PS. Someone created a copy of the "Closed Requests" I deleted the copy thinking nothing of it. Could that have been the issue?

Thank you in advance.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // we need to be in column 13 in order to do something (at all)
  if(e.range.columnStart === 13) {
    var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    
    // only continue if it's completed and where in the correct tab
    if(e.value == "Completed" && s.getName() == "Open Requests") {
      var r = e.range;
      var userEmail = r.offset(0,-9).getValue();
      var name = r.offset(0,-7).getValue();
      var subject = "Technology Request for " + name;
      var body = "Your request has been completed by " + r.offset(0,-1).getValue();    
      
      body += "\nfor -  " + r.offset(0,-7).getValue();
      body += "\nby doing the following: " + r.offset(0,-2).getValue();
      body += "\nOriginal problem was stated as: " + r.offset(0,-4).getValue();
    
      // show dialogue
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var response = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to send this email to ' + userEmail + '?', 'Subject: ' + subject + '\n\n' + body + '\n\n\n', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
     
      // process the user's response.
      if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {name:"Technology Dept"}); 
      }
 
      // add time stamp
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
           
      // move the row elsewhere 
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Closed Requests");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(r.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      s.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
      
      
    } 
  } 
}
```

I have not messed with the script, as it was working.

Comment: From your error of `Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range') onEdit @ Code.gs:3`, your error occurs at `if(e.range.columnStart === 13) {` in your showing script? If my understanding is correct, from `working for more than 5 years`, how have you run your script for 5 years? Can I ask you about the detailed method for executing your showing script? And, I cannot understand `PS. Someone created a copy of the "Closed Requests" I deleted the copy thinking nothing of it.`. Can I ask you about the relationship between this and your showing script?